# Can not add number to pie chart for the slices only a pie chart come without number

Tags: r

I want a create a pie chart below. But I can add the percentage number to the slices. Below is my code. Thanks for helping.

```
slices <- c(51,49)
cs <- c("male", "female")
pie(slices, labels = cs, col=c("blue", "red"), main="Female male ration at Harvard")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do

```r
slices <- c(51,49)
cs <- c("male", "female")
pie(slices, labels = paste0(cs, ' ', slices, '%'),  
    col=c("blue", "red"), main="Female male ratio at Harvard")
```

[image]